# ArrayList of Integers to one int?

Tags: java, arraylist

what would be the easiest way to convert an ArrayList of Integers to one int, with the 1st Integer in the list being the 1st number in the int, etc. in Java?

For example an ArrayList of Integers: 1 4 6 7 8 3 8
becomes the int value 1467838

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Wow, this question got like 10 answers all at once.

Comment: Is the behavior supposed to be specified in cases like List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17); ?

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni: I don't think so.  It seems like what he wants is to combine a list of integers so each integer becomes part of a number.  like in the example, the list combines to become the digits of the final integer.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way in Java is:

```
int total = 0;
for (Integer i : list) { // assuming list is of type List<Integer>
    total = 10*total + i;
}
```

For example, if the list consists of 1 4 6 7 8 3 8, you get:

- `total = 0`
- `total = 10*0 + 1 = 1`
- `total = 10*1 + 4 = 14`
- `total = 10*14 + 6 = 146`
- `...`
- `total = 10*146783 + 8 = 1467838`

which is the correct answer.

Comment: This is the best of the Java answers.  To me, converting to a string and then converting back to an integer is not only inefficient, it's also convoluted.

Comment: To be honest, in Java if you don't care about the efficiency of it, it's not that bad since all the conversions are run by native code.  Though I'll definitely admit it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: This breaks with any integer in the list > 9. I didn't see that constraint in the question, but the fact that the OP marked you as best indicates that all integers in the list are guaranteed to be <= 9.

Comment: Yes, I took the question to mean that the list is a list of digits. If there are multiple-digit numbers in the list, this would break (silently).

Comment: It also has silent overflow problems

Comment: If your list is more than 10 digits, then yes, that would cause problems. Even `longs` max out at 19 digits.

Comment: what if list starts with 0 and I want zero concatenated into int. This would fail.

Answer (score 5):

Note: easiest is not always most efficient.  this is in java since you didn't specify a language.  but you could do something like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(4);
list.add(6);

for (Integer x : list) {
    s += x.toString();
}

Integer finalResult = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

**EDIT**: to please all the people noting this in comments, if you're really worried about efficiency but for some reason want to use this string method, it should be done like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(4);
list.add(6);

String s;

for (Integer x : list) {
    sb.append(x.toString());
}

Integer finalResult = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
```

In the first example, StringBuilder was not used for simplicity's sake, because this looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: thank you so much! very helpful, sorry about the really basic question though

Comment: before i get flamed for being the accepted answer, i will be the first to admit there are faster solutions out there.  this seemed like the simplest for a beginner to understand.

Comment: accepted answer because once I asked, and started looking at the answers, I realized that I already knew that this was what I was trying to do... and it's in java, which is what I wanted but (oops) forgot to say at first!

Comment: @Meg that's fine.  just keep in mind that although you may not notice a difference in speed (i.e. premature optimization), the answers below that do it mathematically will most likely be faster.

Comment: You should use StringBuilder to concatenate your string. Also final is a reserved word.

Comment: Not only are you using string operations, you're using += in a loop. This is pretty much textbook for how *not* to do it--but it does answer the question, and there's no way to know if it will be a bottleneck.

Comment: hmkay... I shall try another way then

Comment: @mmyers and @Steve: yes I'm well aware.  however this is a very simple example and to be honest it sounds like homework.

Comment: it is, homework... sort of

and I wouldn't have asked except everyone else in my class has been looking at like i'm crazy when i tried to ask

Comment: Actually, you don't even have to call x.toString() explicitly. Anyway, as I said earlier, this does answer the question and efficiency was never mentioned. I'm just shooting for the simplest solution.

Comment: @mmyers i'm actually slightly embarrassed to say that i never noticed that about StringBuilder, i.e. it does the String.valueOf conversion for you.  very cool.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming C# (you didn't specify :-), but the general algorithm will work in whatever language you need:

```
int num = 0;
for( int i = 0 ; i < list.Count ; i++ ) 
{
    num *= 10;
    num += (int)list[i];
}
```

Obviously the code assumes that the resulting number is small enough to be represented by int, and that each of the items in your ArrayList is between 0 and 9 both inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Only handles numbers up to 2 billion or so.  Use long, long-long, or your favorite bigint class if you want bigger numbers.  Won't work with negative numbers unless they're all negative.

```
int runningtotal = 0;
foreach(int i in myList) {
    runningtotal *= 10;
    runningtotal += i;
}
return runningtotal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, This will accept numbers > 9

```
List<Integer> list = 
int num = Integer.parseInt(list.toString().replaceAll("\\D",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 0;
for(int i=list.Count - 1;i>=0;--i)
{
  result += list[i] * (int)(Math.Pow((double)10, (double)(list.Count - 1 - i)));
}
```

Also won't work with negative numbers...you could use Math.Abs() to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which language you want, I think your best approach is to find the sum of 1000000 + 400000 + 60000 + 7000 + 800 + 30 + 8

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your question that index 0 of the ArrayList is the most significant value.  Your example show the first number being equivalent to 1,000,000.

You could either treat them as characters then concatenate them then parse back to Integer.

Or you can add each item to the result, then multiply the result by ten to set the magnitudes.

Or you can add each element's value * 10^(count-index); where count is the number of elements in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

In Python! Just for fun:

i = int( "".join( [str(z) for z in x] ) )

Comment: Whoops, this was before you specified a language.  You said ArrayList so I assumed Java, but I just love Python so much.

Comment: it's alright :-) if I ever write something in Python I'll remember it

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell,

```
listToNumber = foldl (\a b -> a*10 + b) 0
```

In Python,

```
def list_to_number(some_list):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*10 + y, some_list, 0)
```

Comment: Posted before the question specified a language.

Comment: Also, being more concise, the Haskell can be reduced to foldl ((+) . (*) 10) 0